# How to solve the error "longtable* is already defined" using package "caption" and documentclass "revtex4"?

Tags: captions, longtable, revtex

I have a serious problem with compilation of the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\captionof{table}{This is a very nice table}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}

\captionof{table}{This is a very nice table}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \longtable* already defined.
>                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
> ```

Could you please help me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, in your code are three problems:

1. Class `revtex4` is outdated, the current one is `revtex4-2`. Can you change?
2. Loading package `caption` results in several errors/warnings for class `revtex4` and for class `revtex4-2`. Just do not load it!
3. `\captionof{table}{This is a very nice table}` is only possible if package `caption` is loaded, but `longtable` defines its own caption with `\caption{This is a very nice table}\\` (please see the closing `\\`!)

With the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4}

\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
\caption{This is a very nice table}\\
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}


\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
\caption{This is a very nice table}\\
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I can compile without errors with class `revtex4` and `revtex4-2`
with the result:

[image: resulting tables]